# PHP shows different timezone for console and web page

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am developing web-site and faced with such problem.

When I run this code in console and web-browser I get different results!!!

```
$dt = new DateTime();
print_r($dt);
```

Result in console:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-01-08 20:58:38.409153
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Moscow
)
```

Result in browser:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-01-08 18:18:33.011310
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

I am using PHP 7.2.10 x64, Win 10, Laravel. php.ini same for console and web

So, please, say me, why I get different results for same code?

Comment: Yes, but 'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE','Europe/Moscow') not working.

Answer (score 0):

The console binary and the web server binary usually use different configuration files. These can contain different settings for timezone. Run `phpinfo()` for the web server or `php -i` for the console to dump settings and then look for "Loaded Configuration File" -- this will tell you what file is being used in each case. Then look for the `date.timezone` setting within those ini files.

You could change them to be the same, or (better) have your application explicitly set the timezone you want (via `date_default_timezone_set()`).

You've also mentioned Laravel, which probably has its own configuration settings that override the default. (I am not familiar with where Laravel stores its config though.)

Comment: Already checked -  same for both D:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP-7.2-x64\php.ini